# How do I fix these package dependency issues?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, updates, dependencies

I can't install anything right now (or upgrade anything). When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade I get [this list of unmet dependencies](http://paste.ubuntu.com/858100/). At the end it says

> E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

When I try `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.6-base libacl1 libasound2 libasound2-plugins libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libattr1 libaudio2 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libc6 libcairo2 libcomerr2 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3 libdatrie1
  libdb5.1 libdbus-1-3 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libexpat1 libffi6
  libflac8 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libgdbm3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libgnutls26 libgpg-error0 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk2.0-0 libice6
  libidn11 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1 libjpeg62 libjson0 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  liblcms1 libldap-2.4-2 libllvm2.9 libmng1 libnspr4 libnspr4-0d libnss3 libnss3-1d libogg0 libpango1.0-0
  libpciaccess0 libpcre3 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libpulse0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 librtmp0
  libsamplerate0 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsdl1.2debian-alsa libselinux1 libsm6 libsndfile1 libspeexdsp1
  libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libtasn1-3 libthai0 libtiff4 libuuid1 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libwrap0
  libx11-6 libxau6 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6
  libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxt6 libxv1 libxxf86vm1 zlib1g
The following packages will be upgraded:
  myunity
1 upgraded, 118 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 144 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'libc6'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

Nothing happens though. I don't really know what's going on, or how to troubleshoot this. I looked at `man 5 apt.conf` under Immedate-Configure, but it didn't really tell me anything.

I'm kind of skeptical that all these things need to be installed. I think there's just an error reading some package list or something, so it doesn't know what's installed or not. But I could be wrong about that.

How can I fix these dependency issues?

Comment: Maybe some packaging error on myunity's side? Try to disable that PPA and see what happens if you do a: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran

`sudo apt-get -o APT::Immediate-Configure=no upgrade`

using someone else's suggestion. After that I ran

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

and together they seem to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure how it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

That suggestion from the tool is a bit ambiguous if not misleading. You are supposed to run `sudo apt-get install -f` and **NOT** `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`.

Read more about the `-f` option in `man apt-get`. It is a bit dense, but it says that `-f` is expected to work with `apt-get install` and `apt-get remove`.

Comment: `apt-get install -f` gave me similar messages.

Comment: Try getting into single user mode and running this again. The package list shown will probably not be downloaded and installed (it says 0 bytes to download). It is probably some aborted installation earlier which left some packages unconfigured.

Since `libc6` is practically used all the time when you are doing real work, maybe going into single user mode can help you fix it.

Comment: Never mind. Saw your answer up there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar packages dependencies problem (Ubuntu 12.10). I fixed it by unticking (in the Software Sources Updates tab):" Pre-released updates (quantal-proposed) " and
" Unsupported updates (quantal-backports) "

Worked for me!

Some times it's something as easy as that other times? Not so..................